# Modelling in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table, modeling

I'm working on a large project at the moment and am just wondering which is best practice, to model entities and sets of entities seperately or in one class?

Currently I am implementing two classes for each entity (for example an 'author' and 'authors' class) where the plural class contains methods like 'fetch authors' (using Zend_Db_Table_Abstract for plural and Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract for singular).

However I realised that I've often seen methods like 'fetch/list' functions in a single entity's object, which seems quite neat in terms of the fact that I won't have to have as many files.

I know there are no hard-and-fast rules for data modelling but before I continue too far I'd be interested in learning what the general consensus on best-practice for this is (along with supporting arguments of course!).

Answers [opinions] gratefully received!

Rob Ganly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I prefer a model called `Person` to actually represent a single person and a model like `PersonCollection` to represent a collection of persons. In neither case, would I have methods for fetch/get on these objects. Rather, I would put those methods on a `PersonRepository` or a `PersonMapper` class.

That's really my biggest area of discomfort with ActiveRecord as a pattern for modeling. By having methods like `find()` and `save()`, it opens the door to methods like `getPersonByName()`, `getPersonsWithMinimumAge()`, etc. These methods are great, nothing wrong with them, but I think that semantically, they work better on a mapper or a repository class. Let the `Model` actually model, leave persistence and retrieval to mappers and repositories.

So, to more directly address your question, I see potentially three classes per "entity type":

1. `Person` - actually models a person
2. `PersonCollection` - extends some Abstract Collection class, each item of class Person
3. `PersonMapper` - persistence and retrieval of `Person` objects and `PersonCollections`

Controllers would use the mapper to persist and retrieve models and collections.

It's probably no surprise that I'm drawn to Doctrine2. The `EntityManager` there functions as a single point of contact for persistence and retrieval. I can then create repositories and services that use the `EntityManager` for custom functionality. And I can then layer on action helpers or factories or dependency injection containers to make it easy to get/create those repositories and services.

But I know that the standard ActiveRecord approach is quite common, well-understood, and very  mainstream. You can get good results using it and can find many developers who immediately understand it and can work well with it.

As in most things, YMMV.

Comment: I prefer the "same" concept. Only difference: No Collection object, my Mapper is returning altough "collections" as array of Models. I like it simple :-)

Comment: @ArneRie: Yeah, I confess that I don't always go the Collection route, either. But as long as it implements the Iterator interface, I get to use it pretty much just like an array. And, in principle, it does allow some flexibility for the collection itself to have attributes and behaviors: `$fishCaughtInTheNet->getNumberOfDistinctSpecies()`, `$prescriptions->haveNotableInteractions()`. `$locations->areWithinRadius($someRadius)`. Fun stuff like that, but probably not all that critical in your standard CRUD-like application. Thanks and cheers! ;-)

Comment: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html - Is or was as reference in the Quickstart/Manual. So also Zend recommends the usage of a DataMapper-Pattern.